# DataGrid template

Tags: c#, wpf

I am doing a template for a project and I found a problem, I can not erase the line pointed in the image. Can anybody help me? Here is the code that I have and if anyone sees some improvement to make, less code or whatever, let me know :)

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TemplateImage">
        <Image Source="1.png" Margin="5" Height="30"/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="Template">
        <Label x:Name="Label" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock x:Name="Texto" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="11" Padding="10,5,0,5" TextDecorations="Underline"/>
        </Label>
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridCell}}}" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="Texto" Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="LightGray"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,0,10,0"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <ContentPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF324549"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,5"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Verdana"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Grid>
                        <themes:DataGridHeaderBorder BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                                                     BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                                                     Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                                                     IsClickable="{TemplateBinding CanUserSort}" 
                                                     IsPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}" 
                                                     IsHovered="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" 
                                                     Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                                     SortDirection="{TemplateBinding SortDirection}" 
                                                     SeparatorBrush="Transparent"
                                                     SeparatorVisibility="Hidden">
                            <Border CornerRadius="5" Padding="30,8,30,8">
                                <!--<Border.Effect>
                                    <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="4" Color="DarkGray" Opacity=".6" RenderingBias="Performance"/>
                                </Border.Effect>-->
                                <Border.Background>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF26373B" Offset="0.767"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF627378" Offset="0.832"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF26373B" Offset="0.914"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Border.Background>
                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                                  RecognizesAccessKey="True" 
                                                  SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" 
                                                  VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                            </Border>
                        </themes:DataGridHeaderBorder>
                        <!--<Thumb x:Name="PART_LeftHeaderGripper" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                        <Thumb x:Name="PART_RightHeaderGripper" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>-->
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="2"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="SizeWE"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=DataGridSelectAllButtonStyle, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type DataGrid}}" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="Border" Fill="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>
                        <Polygon x:Name="Arrow" Fill="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="8,8,3,3" Opacity="0.15" Points="0,10 10,10 10,0" Stretch="Uniform" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="Border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Arrow" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF688CAF"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="RowDetailsVisibilityMode" Value="VisibleWhenSelected"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="Both"/>
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                            Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="DG_ScrollViewer" Focusable="False">
                            <ScrollViewer.Template>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter x:Name="PART_ColumnHeadersPresenter" Grid.Column="1" Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Column}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                                        <ScrollContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter" CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1"/>
                                        <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar" Grid.Column="2" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"/>
                                        <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2">
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding NonFrozenColumnsViewportHorizontalOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar" Grid.Column="1" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}" Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Grid>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </ScrollViewer.Template>
                            <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsGrouping" Value="true"/>
                    <Condition Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping" Value="False"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="False"/>
            </MultiTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your margin property has a bottom value of 1. Try changing it to 0.

OLD:

```
<Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,1"/>
```

NEW:

```
<Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is not the solution :(

Comment: Dang, well I'd definitely check all your margins.